# How can i fix this error? DiscoveryService: basic error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"basic"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, smartcontracts, discovery, chaincode

I'm at my final configuration step of my HF network. After I enroll an admin and an user, i have this error when i try to execute my class "invoke.js" (node invoke.js). The error is:

**error: [DiscoveryService]: send[basic] - Channel:examplechannel received discovery error:failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"basic" >
Failed to submit transaction: Error: DiscoveryService: basic error: failed constructing descriptor for chaincodes:<name:"basic" >**

The chaincode's name is 'basic' and the name of the channel is 'examplechannel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can come if wrong chaincode name is used with invoke. Make sure chaincode with name "basic" is deployed to the "examplechannel" before invoke.